# Android - Writing object to file to ftp server, and then reading that file from the ftp server.

Tags: android, ftp, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to write an array as a file to a server using objectoutput stream, then read that file as an array back into the program.

```
String UserInfo[] = {UserName, FirstName, LastName, Age, Gender, EMail, PhoneNumber};
FileOutputStream SaveUserInfoOS;
SaveUserInfoOS = openFileOutput(UserName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(SaveUserInfoOS);
oos.writeObject(UserInfo);
```

At this point I really don't know how to upload it to the FTP Server because I don't know how to get it as a file.

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect("server", "port");
client.login("Username", "Pass");
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE, FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
File file = new File("/path/to/filetotranfer");
FileInputStream ifile = new FileInputStream(file);

// Upload file to FTP Server
client.storeFile("filetotranfer",ifile);
client.disconnect();
```

My question is, how can I get the saved array as a file to put into the server, and then retrieve, and is there any way to directly save it to the server? Lastly, is there any more efficient way to do all of this that I'm missing?

Comment: You need to write the file out to a file before you use FTP. You can write it out to temporary storage in android and then ftp from same location.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing to the outputstream why don't you [appendFileStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net//apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#appendFileStream%28java.lang.String%29) method